# Google QPX Express API still working?

Tags: api, flightpath

Google QPX Express API (google flight api) still working? I cannot find the API on google library to activate. But on their demo page i can make requests. Can anybody give me a solution for this?

Comment: The QPX Express API service will end on April 10, 2018
 [link] https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/